# finding common word appear in a column and removing them

Tags: r, nlp, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with a column consist of texts strings.

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c("one three", "one four five", "one two five", "one three five six")
```

I need to find all common words appear in second column (this case of example, the word 'one' appears in each row of second column.

then I need to remove that common word and get new df:

```
newdf <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c("three", "four five", "two five", "three five six")
```

I tried using functions like intersect, string grp() but could not achieve. Any tidyverse or similar tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#sample data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 text = c("one three", "one four five", "one two five", "one three five six"))
#find common words
common.words <- Reduce(intersect, strsplit(df$text, " "))
#remove comming words, trim leftover whitespace
df$text2 <- trimws(gsub(paste0(common.words, collapse = "|"), "", df$text))
#   id               text          text2
# 1  1          one three          three
# 2  2      one four five      four five
# 3  3       one two five       two five
# 4  4 one three five six three five six
```

**update for multiple columns**

```
#sample data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 text = c("one three", "one four three five", "one two five", "one three five six"),
                 text2 = c("five one three", "one four three five", "one two five", "one three five six"))


library(data.table)
#make data a data.table
setDT(df)
#columns to analyse
textcols <- c("text", "text2")
#check: find common words by column
# df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) Reduce(intersect, strsplit(x, " "))), .SDcols = textcols]
df[, (textcols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    common.words <- Reduce(intersect, strsplit(x, " "))
    trimws(gsub(paste0(common.words, collapse = "|"), "", x))
  }),
  .SDcols = textcols]
```

Comment: wow thats fabolous and swift...just a bonus (for me he he) if I need to apply for each column with its own common words how would i expand?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` as well

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 text = c("one three", "one four five", "one two five", "one three five six"),
                 text2= c("two three", "two four five", "two five", "two three five six"),
                 text3 = c("one two three", "one four five two", "one two five", "one three five two six"))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, ~stringi::stri_extract_all_words(..1) %>% 
                                            reduce(intersect) %>% 
                                            paste0(., collapse = "|") %>% 
                                            str_remove_all(..1, .) %>% 
                                            str_trim)
  id           text          text2           text3
1  1          three          three           three
2  2      four five      four five       four five
3  3       two five           five            five
4  4 three five six three five six three five  six
```

Put the function into a named list to preserve the columns

```
mutate_if(is.character, list(new=~stringi::stri_extract_all_words(..1) %>% 
                                            reduce(intersect) %>% 
                                            paste0(., collapse = "|") %>% 
                                            str_remove_all(..1, .) %>% 
                                            str_trim))
```

The output is then:

```
  id               text              text2                  text3       text_new      text2_new       text3_new
1  1          one three          two three          one two three          three          three           three
2  2      one four five      two four five      one four five two      four five      four five       four five
3  3       one two five           two five           one two five       two five           five            five
4  4 one three five six two three five six one three five two six three five six three five six three five  six
```